# Can i call an anonymous function later on

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I was working on a function in JavaScript and i wondered if i could call a anonymous function later on:

```
code
more code

(function() {
alert('Hello World!');
})();
more code
(function() {
alert('Goodbye World!');
})();

//call to the first anonymous function
//call to the first anonymous function
```

Is it possible to call anonymous functions?
I imagine there could be an array containing all functions?

Comment: Can you elaborate __later__ ?

Comment: I will stay online until i get an answer, so if you have a question or a suggestion regarding my question please ask, if you down vote please explain why so i can learn from it !

Comment: Sure, later in the script when the code has passed by the anonymous function

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible in a portable manner. But why would you want to do that? Just assign it to a variable!

Comment: Can you then use that variable to call the function later on?

Comment: I agree with Niklas, if you don't want to use a regular function, use a lambda assigned to a variable. More here http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1031-javascript-jems-lambda-expressions.htm

Comment: Yeah sure. You can also use the `function NAME() {...}` syntax

Comment: you have to assign the anonymous function to a variable. e.g. var test = function (){};. You have two Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) defined. It's probably worth you working out the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Since functions are "first class citizens" you can assign them to variables, or put them into arrays/objects whatever just like any other var, whether they're anonymous or not.

So you'll have to assign the anonymous function to a variable (or put it into an array) in order to have some kind of means to reference it later on.

Furthermore, you don't execute it immediately, rather you execute it at a later time.

```
var anon1 = (function(){
    alert("anon1");
}); // <-- no () so it doesn't execute now.

// code code

anon1(); // <-- execute now

// ----- or -------
var myFuncs = [];

myFuncs.push( (function(){
    alert("in myFuncs");
}) ); // <-- not executing it here.

// code code

myFuncs[0](); // <-- execute now
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap your functions in parentheses.

Comment: Just trying to maintain consistency with original question for the question asker's sake.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but the parentheses are only required for the IIFE, so to leave them when you aren't doing an IIFE is wrong. If I had to maintain a codebase where the dev had wrapped all their function expressions in parentheses, the first thing I would do is refactor it to remove them.